# When should @ be escaped in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

In the below example I can't see escaping `@` makes any difference, which I find a bit surprising, as it would be required in Perl.

In which situations should `@` be escaped in bash?

```
TYPE="snap"
zfsPath="tank/fs"

(
echo "tank/fs@snap1"
echo "tank/fs/fs2@snap2"
) | grep "$zfsPath\@${TYPE}"
```

Comment: It looks like the last line contains a backslash to visually denote the end of the variable name. As bash is not perl, there are different rules: @ does not require escaping in bash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Perl, `@` must be escaped to prevent array interpolation in double quotes:

```
print "somebody@example.com"; # This would interpolate the array `@example`
```

In bash, arrays are not denoted by the @ sigil. Therefore, you do not have to backslash the at sign in a similar context. `@` is special in bash in other contexts, though, as in `$@` or `${array[@]}`, so if you want to print such a string literally, you have to use single quotes (backslashing @ does not help), or you have to backslash the `$`:

```
echo "\$@"
echo "\${array[2]}"
```